# How to get the result of a Javascript BigInt division in significants and exponent

Tags: javascript, bigint

I would like to divide two BigInt numbers and get the result as some significant digits and an exponent. I have got this so far:

```
f = (numerator, denominator, significantsLength) => {
      const denominatorLength = ('' + denominator).length
      const extension = significantsLength + denominatorLength
      const extendedNumerator = numerator * 10n ** BigInt(extension)
      const div = extendedNumerator / denominator
      const divLength = ('' + div).length
      const digitsSurplus = divLength - significantsLength
      const significants = div / 10n ** BigInt(digitsSurplus)
      const exponent = digitsSurplus - extension
      return significants + 'e' + exponent
    }
```

so `f(1n,3n,3)` results in `'333e-3'`

Could it be better? This code does not round up. It also does not work well with zero and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) to make a division between two BigIntegers and then represent it with an exponent with `n` significant digits:

### Try it here

```js
// Number of decimals needed
Base.setDecimals(100);

let x = Base('555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555');
let y = Base('999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999');

let z = x.divide(y);

console.log( z.toString() );
console.log( z.toExponential(4) );
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```

#### Negative numbers

```js
// Number of decimals needed
Base.setDecimals(100);

let x = Base('-1e+1000');
let y = Base(9);

let z = x.divide(y);

console.log( z.toString() );
console.log( z.toExponential(10) );
```

```html
 <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```